# Mysql - Como eliminar registros que superaron un tiempo determinado desde su momento de creacion?

Tags: mysql

Tengo un formulario de inicio de sesion juntamente con una opcion para reestablecer su contraseña, cuando el usuario solicita reestablecer su contraseña el sistema automaticamente le envia un codigo de seguridad a su correo electronico que posteriormente el usuario lo tiene que introducir para autorizar el cambio de contraseña. Este codigo se almacena en una tabla de mi base de datos y lo que trato de hacer es de que todos aquellos codigos que hayan superado los 60 minutos desde su fecha de creacion sean eliminados ya que el codigo solo tendra una vigencia de 1 hora (60 min). Tengo el siguiente script en php pero no funciona.

```
private function actualizarCodigos(){
        /**
         * EN ESTA FUNCION LO QUE SE HACE ES ELIMINAR LOS CODIGOS QUE EXPIRARON LOS 60MIN(1 HORA).
         */
        try {
            $this->clase_dbconexion = new dbconexion();
            $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->conectar();
            $consulta = $conexion->prepare("DELETE FROM aclcose WHERE cacofeccre > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)");
            $consulta->execute();
            $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->desconectar($conexion);
            return true;

        } catch (PDOException $exception) {
            //echo('Se produjo un error al registrar en la tabla Cliente: ' . $exception->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- cacocorele = Correo electronico.
- cacofeccre = Fecha de Creacion.
- cacocodseg = Codigo de Seguridad.

Comment: nos mencionas que no funciona, ¿obtienes algún error o algún resultado?

Comment: No obtengo ningun error, simplemente no se eliminan los registros, no se si el sql estara bien o no, ya que ese codigo lo saque de internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analicemos la condicion que usas

```
cacofeccre > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE)
```

O sea, estamos buscando que cacofeccre (ni voy a preguntar por el nombre del campo) sea **mayor** que este momento mas 60 minutos.

Y no, eso nunca va a pasar.. si cacofeccre es un momento en el pasado, nunca va a ser mayor a un momento que es ahora (que es el futuro) mas 60 minutos (que es mas futuro que ese futuro de antes)

lo que vos querias, realmente, es que cacofeccre + 60 minutos fuera menor a este momento... o sea, haya pasado mas de una hora...

prueba asi:

```
DATE_ADD(cacofeccre, INTERVAL 60 MINUTE) < NOW()
```

Comment: Genial, funciona.